# Returning a Stream of Entities using a Transactor inside a Resource in Doobie

Tags: postgresql, scala, fs2, doobie

I'm trying to implement a query that returns the extracted information inside a `fs2.Stream`. I defined the `Jobs` algebra:

```scala
trait Jobs[F[_]] {
  def all(): fs2.Stream[F, Job]
}
```

Then, I implemented an interpreter for the algebra:

```scala
final class LiveJobs[F[_]: MonadCancelThrow](postgres: Resource[F, Transactor[F]]) extends Jobs[F] {
  override def all(): fs2.Stream[F, Job] = for {
    jobs <- postgres.use { xa =>
      sql"SELECT * FROM jobs".query[Job].stream.transact(xa)
    }
  } yield jobs
}
```

However, the compiler yells because the types are not aligned:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : fs2.Stream[[_]F[_],Job]
[error]  required: F[?]
[error]       sql"SELECT * FROM jobs".query[Job].stream.transact(xa)
[error]                                                         ^
[error] one error found
```

The `Resource.use` method needs a function that produces an `F[*]`, not an `fs2.Stream[F, Job]`. I cannot find anything that lets me convert between the two types or a different way to use the `postgres` resource.

Comment: You want `Stream.resource(postgres).flatMap(xa => sql"SELECT * FROM jobs".query[Job].stream.transact(xa))` - also, you probably do not want to adquiere the transactor for each query, rather, the constructor of that class should receive the transactor directly and the factory of the class should return a `Resource` of itself.

Comment: Many thanks, Luis. So, the transaction will be acquired every time I call `use`? Hmm, terrible idea. Thanks a lot. If you want to answer the question, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is probably the design you want to follow:

```scala
trait Jobs[F[_]] {
  def all: fs2.Stream[F, Job] =
}

object Jobs {
  // I am not exactly sure which typeclass you require here, so i will use Async
  def live[F[_]](implicit ev: Async[F]): Resource[F, Jobs[F]] = {
    val transactor: Resource[F, Transactor[F]] = ... // Whatever you already have here.
    transactor.map(xa => new LiveJobs(xa))
  }
}

private[pckg] final class LiveJobs[F[_]](xa: Transactor[F])(implicit ev: MonadCancelThrow[F]) extends Jobs[F] {
  override final val all: fs2.Stream[F, Job] =
    sql"SELECT * FROM jobs".query[Job].stream.transact(xa)
}
```

---

Also, my personal advice, stick to concrete `IO` while learning; and maybe even after.
The whole `F[_]` thing will just cause more trouble than worth originally.

Comment: Thanks, Luis. Only one more question: Why should the factory return a `Resource[F, Jobs[F]]`? I mean, `Jobs` algebra (and its interpreter) is not a resource.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin because in order to create a `LiveJobs` instance you need a `Transactor` which is a resource that has to be acquired and released, thus your implementation life-cycle is tied to that one, if you want to use the instance you need the transactor open and if you close / free the instance you want to close the transactor, does that makes sense?

Comment: > if you close / free the instance you want to close the transaction
So, if the `Transactor` is shared among more than one algebra, I can avoid the factory returning a `Resource`. Is it right?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin if the `Transactor` is required in many then yeah, the factory method `live` will receive a `(xa: Transactor[F])` and return a `Jobs[F]` directly _(and probably would only require `MonadCancelThrow[F]` rather than `Async[F]`)_

Comment: Many thanks. I really appreciate your patience :)